# How to not display UI from an UWP app deployed in hololens?

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, augmented-reality, hololens

I have created an UWP app with UI created with XAML that has 2 parts.
One that executes on the Hololens and one that executes on a PC.

From the PC, you can see what the hololens camera sees.
On the Hololens app, you dont need to see anything from the app. No UI.

Currently, on the Hololens I see a window with the same UI that I see on the PC app, when I deploy it. I need the app to execute on the hololens, but I dont want the hololens user to see any UI.

The reason I am asking this, its because I have used unity and holotoolkit there. When I enabled virtual reality under player settings, deployed on UWP, I achieved the thing that I am asking. So i know it can be done.
The question is how to do this in UWP app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The reason I am asking this, its because I have used unity and holotoolkit there. When I enabled virtual reality under player settings, deployed on UWP, I achieved the thing that I am asking. So i know it can be done. The question is how to do this in UWP app.

For UWP apps, you could not achieve this target. If you want to run the UWP app, the window always will show. So, what you said "No UI" is impossible. When you enabled virtual reality under player settings, then you could see what the hololens camera sees directly. This should be a function of Unity IDE. This function is convenient for the hololens developers to develop their hololens apps. Unity should has done some deep integration by some underlying SDK, but in UWP, you could not do it.